# xcode view doesn't show url image

Tags: ios, swift, image, url

I'm studying the iOS development course of Stanford, and I copied the sample code that worked perfectly fine in the course to my Xcode. The view just doesn't show the url image and I have already set the Allow Arbitrary Loads in info to "yes". There are no error appears on screen but the view shows nothing.

```
  class ImageViewController: UIViewController

    {

    var imageURL: URL? {
       didSet {
         image = nil
            if view.window != nil {
             fetchImage()
            }
        }
    }

    private func fetchImage() {
         if let url = imageURL {
         let urlContents = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
           if let imageData = urlContents {
              image = UIImage(data: imageData)
           }
        }
    }

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    imageURL = DemoURL.stanford // for demo/testing purposes only 


 //This is the url image. It is in another swift file，the address is ( static let stanford = URL(string: "http://stanford.edu/about/images/intro_about.jpg"，) I can open it in safari.

}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
   super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    if image == nil { // we're about to appear on screen so, if needed,
      fetchImage() // fetch image
    }
}


fileprivate var imageView = UIImageView()
private var image: UIImage? {
       get {
          return imageView.image
         }
       set {
      imageView.image = newValue
      imageView.sizeToFit()
    // careful here because scrollView might be nil
    // (for example, if we're setting our image as part of a prepare)
    // so use optional chaining to do nothing
      // if our scrollView outlet has not yet been set

     }
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the code that downloads the image?

Comment: I would fetch via an URLSession, instead from Data  since you can check the response to see if there is an error, statusCode in such ?

Answer (score 0):

The URL from DemoURL.swift doesn't exist ... you can for example write in DemoURL.swift :

```
static let stanford = URL(string:"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cd/Stanford_Oval_May_2011_panorama.jpg/800px-Stanford_Oval_May_2011_panorama.jpg")
```

Answer (score 0):

1) don't use synchronous calls:

see at:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1407864-init

2) use a NSURL session in this way:

```
let myURL = URL(string: "https: ......")        
let session = URLSession.shared
let task = session.dataTask(with: myURL!) { (data, resp, err) in

        var statusCode: NSInteger = 0
        if let httpResponse : HTTPURLResponse = resp as? HTTPURLResponse{
            statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode
        }

        if let data = data, statusCode == 200{
            if let img = UIImage(data: data){
            // use your image...

           }
        }
    }
```

3) do not use http, Apple want https since ios9.